# Dynamic Linq query for join two tables with more than one condition(dynamically)

Tags: c#, linq, join, entity-framework-5, expression

Condition will be specified at run time only

I tried to inner join with two tables with one condition dynamically, It is working fine.
but with two or more condition dynamically ,its not working.Please help me solve this problem

Please see the cases

**case 1:** join with one condition (**working fine**)

```
Base entity:User

entity to join :Role

condition to join: Role.Id = User.RoleId


//select * from User inner join Role on User.RoleId=Role.Id

//static way

     IQueryable<UserEntity> query =
        db.Set<user>().Join(db.Set<Role>(), 
        user =>  User.RoleId, 
        role=> role.Id, 
        (user , role) => new { user , role }).Select(temp=> temp.user);



//Dynamic Way **(working fine)**           


 ParameterExpression lambdaExprVar_Role = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Role), "role");

            PropertyInfo rightPropertyInfo_role = typeof(Role).GetProperty("Id");

            Expression rightExpression_role = Expression.Property(lambdaExprVar_Role, rightPropertyInfo_role );

            Expression<Func<Role, Int64>> myexp_role = Expression.Lambda<Func<Role, Int64>>(rightExpression_role , new ParameterExpression[] { lambdaExprVar_Role });                  

            ParameterExpression lambdaExprVar_User = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "user");

            PropertyInfo rightPropertyInfo_user = typeof(User).GetProperty("RoleId");

            Expression rightExpression_user = Expression.Property(lambdaExprVar_User, rightPropertyInfo_user);

            Expression<Func<User, Int64>> myexp_user = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, Int64>>(rightExpression_user, new ParameterExpression[] { lambdaExprVar_User });       

    IQueryable<OrganizationNode> query = db.Set<User>()
                .Join(db.Set<Role>(), myexp_user, myexp_role, (user, role) => new {user, role})
                .Select(temp=>temp.user);
```

**case 2:** join with two condition(not working)

```
Base entity:User

entity to join :Role

condition to join: Role.Id==User.RoleId,Role.Code==User.RoleCode

//select * from User inner join Role on User.RoleId=Role.Id and User.RoleCode=Role.Code

//static way **(working fine)**



    IQueryable<User> query =
        db.Set<user>().Join(db.Set<Role>(), 
        **user => new { matchId = user.RoleId, matchcode= user.RoleCode}, 
        role=> new { matchId = role.Id, matchcode= role.code},** 
        (user , role) => new { user , role }).Select(temp=> temp.user);

//Dynamic Way   (**** not working)
```

Help me to write/rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
from u in db.Set<user>
inner join r in db.Set<Role>
on new {r.Id, r.Code} equals {u.RoleId, u.RoleCode)
select u
```

Another way to write the above linq query would be the following:

```
from u in db.Set<user>
from r in db.Set<Role>.Where(r.Id==RoleId && u.RoleCode==r.Code)
select u
```